# Invalid token in member declaration

Tags: c#, list, class, declaration

I'm trying to declare this item for use in a list.

```
class Item
{
    Public int Resource{ get;set; }
    Public long Offset{ get;set; }
    Public int Value{ get;set; }
}
```

I thought this would be ok, I copied it off someone else, but I don't understand what get and set do. I'm completely new to C#, but the tutorial I watched put their class declaration in a different file - do you have to do that?

I get this error:

> Line: 15 Column: 11 (CS1519) Invalid token 'int' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: Please put the rest of your code !

Comment: Please share (at least) the line (15) which causes the given error.

Comment: It is `public`, not `Public`.

Comment: Please read [Using Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)!

Comment: A schoolboy error! Thanks Milster.

Comment: Line 15 is probably there. The issue was resolved as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# case sensitive, write public in lower case:

```
class Item
{
    public int Resource { get; set; }
    public long Offset { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Get and sen in this example do nothing (almost) more info about them:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties